# WordPress Grooni Crane Theme Content before the menu bar feature

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, themes

I am using a licenced version of the WordPress Grooni Crane theme

https://crane.grooni.com/promo/
https://grooni.com/docs/crane/search/crane_before_primary_menu_area

I want to add content and images to a section ABOVE the Groovy Menu Plugin (comes with the Grooni theme).

So usually I would create te HTML of the images and content and forcefully add it into the header.php file before the menu gets shown, but upon doing this I saw that the PHP now allows for a content section to be added / displayed before the menu will be displayed using crane_before_primary_menu_area .

My question is: How / where in the Grooni Crane theme do I create / edit this section, so that I dont have to force the HTML into the header file, but so that it rather get added dynamicly using the proper functions.

Code in the header.php file looks like this:

```
do_action( 'crane_before_primary_menu_area' );
do_action( 'crane_primary_menu_area' );
do_action( 'crane_after_primary_menu_area' );
```

So it shows 'crane_before_primary_menu_area' first, then it shows the menu bar, and then it should show 'crane_after_primary_menu_area'.

My Question is where / how (on the wordpress CMS) do I create / edit a content section for 'crane_before_primary_menu_area' & 'crane_after_primary_menu_area'

Answer (score 0):

This must be done through the child theme.
Together with the Crane theme It was bundled. 
Activate it or create your own new one.
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Insert the hook into the functions.php file that will be called in the action 'crane_before_primary_menu_area'

Sample contents of functions.php for child theme

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists('custom_func__crane_before_primary_menu_area')) {
    add_action( 'crane_before_primary_menu_area', 'custom_func__crane_before_primary_menu_area' );
    function custom_func__crane_before_primary_menu_area() {
        $html_content = '<div>Content before menu area</div>';
        echo $html_content;
    }
}
```

In the above example, we assigned HTML text to the variable

```
$html_content = '<div> Content before menu area </div>';
```

And immediately it was shown to the front

```
echo $html_content;
```

However inside the function
function custom_func__crane_before_primary_menu_area () {.......}
you can call any other available functions, and display any content you wish.